# How to decrypt an encrypted payload in hyperledger?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am currently using Hyperledger Fabric. I am using the REST API to make GET request as so:

> curl 172.18.0.3:7050/chain/blocks/31

And the output I am getting back is :

```
{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "type": 2,
      "chaincodeID": "BMBQHHg2y0RnadYEaZZT8icjMvZbDPjkn5mFb+clFORxJqz8qsMs/QlalCT+A3msuc59KYM5sbZyhM3OeSplTWo91WAHTUgqIKVrm1gUzsouBIqLNvpqgimN36+s0ywF0Rx4gn27RmQYBbB+877Nh+w7A8Ezz92T1MgHcmzfRgVaDmiN0ga+jAfufNYglmeM4ZSysmSsz6xJtrcD5mTmHXZtvtw6uGCI1TCOMBaWTpLhNHfM2/5EB5jatdMjDi1GAlaXkDWcLgGjScL1yZpWcntz/N0cT90r6i9ycXZ0kk9wodBq2cFutDTdkl8S90kzd0gXig==",
      "payload":"BBYZD6S/hRILcf21zVbhMAhA+qLQvAq+KvOBuXOknPCAMjas2LI9f42AKG6r+uWP71LYEkbo1XXANuDmukZjDsFGltzoIfq+Mry5n/CNXzXgiVLX0J7z08kGfEfw2vnywgmVFX4UtKPpl8pMTmRxJWn5Q0HY1pFnA6ZaXluoLRf7f17Ko4SPahi19k2NszcJ0SHE7xRllfLXZJxaOlT2J56nqjTBKTJ86bdqn6AdQXHA6Px7yz5XpgJhccyecaLS4sYcsrqHoOlO+kk+bw5Q6qnkHfIIhLXCEgHxKoT00L8I8B2luO1RlmQd4mNfXb7GrLOJXvCNPrcpSEmQDByEGwn1j3Zy0lilwKVaNYTPNThMwQ==",
      "txid": "72bd2ab7-f769-49c9-a754-c7be0c481cf0",
      "timestamp": {
        "seconds": 1496062124,
        "nanos": 474977395
      },
      "confidentialityLevel": 1,
      "confidentialityProtocolVersion": "1.2",
      "nonce": "2YgU+0WYPuTKGsKkT1hx7McOURPTIRgG",
      "toValidators": "BJWJi5aSycSaJBaLIciUxlhZNyRsW6es2pO7ljUmqxP2SLzgUJtDtAeG8S5SMq+RQ9iX9m8+HIUocrD2J1MBTJaxPWcs/dYFNp1zi8k1ogbEuIQJDe/Gb0mbYVoBqGgFjofiE2lrZTO+RBVmUBQkAoybloOMUSfMawpOPTt/cIeNBq3M+t6gbTSl0ZVs5ofITWtonwhG8PNnlZwEmTLkC7evX1ImivMqo47ONxHXJlbbtjf+pL5kaqU5DrXWiv2L6Wt0xc11od4rbotnAQP2w2dqKTy2fj4ON6qCBp8i+t2FRi/iO0INJpI0aDjdkVCR",
      "cert": "MIICUjCCAfigAwIBAgIRAJOBK8HG3E/Pmw8fZwL4iuswCgYIKoZIzj0EAwMwMTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFDASBgNVBAoTC0h5cGVybGVkZ2VyMQwwCgYDVQQDEwN0Y2EwHhcNMTcwNTI5MTEyNzQwWhcNMTcwODI3MTEyNzQwWjBFMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEUMBIGA1UEChMLSHlwZXJsZWRnZXIxIDAeBgNVBAMTF1RyYW5zYWN0aW9uIENlcnRpZmljYXRlMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE6QVLJ48eCVlS1S8/BiSTU1XiWR0tZ6NGF3OZr306sTcgG/nYtcjx6/yJNwDgdYz5Boi7sA2QWUcqUkWfIPNWPKOB3DCB2TAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADANBgNVHQ4EBgQEAQIDBDAPBgNVHSMECDAGgAQBAgMEME0GBioDBAUGBwEB/wRArYyx9l4zJL4TbxDHuGZBsJ545Jsph/D/Q/FgMTTtxPh93B+LV6AI1tyFVHWiKNS4GgvDVlmgfwFuMAca+/PaujBKBgYqAwQFBggEQPEdAS1h/9LJJmqriV+42k0bL+ghGFbHa5GiEAitiMjlduiwgfelPK/rbAq0a6NrnPXCEYe1aWCSqyqsEfHGBoIwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwMDSAAwRQIhAOidYaESZ3xyZBTgcBOm3zyXvGb4YCCt7I7+M0gZF4xzAiAgYuCf7FPGx3fnJdABlZjszA1pR6jaPtIOQN2ndfAFZA==",
      "signature": "MEUCIQCVBtfjk3yzwfOFyOojH5tynq3HrG7dFN9URXB5C6kYDAIgLPcwJBAIVlD1I4dxzczfxmywlZn1ZMSvL2djioWgqFQ="
    }
  ],
  "stateHash": "9KEsiBp4t/VZyETXMASSYtuPuf8JowktCSbX7daPt69uqDzrJvifrPIXpI5N1kOayoq6H0afM8zN/WZpWsesHQ==",
  "previousBlockHash": "v6Fo6SARD0xdE0B/jvIq22kgV5uLAKhTwLjrA4YRBskWcZOjECFbNgzlwFQhEmbar1zcAbcZVo9eo/3tx2y68g==",
  "consensusMetadata": "CCA=",
  "nonHashData": {
    "localLedgerCommitTimestamp": {
      "seconds": 1496062125,
      "nanos": 496018341
    },
    "chaincodeEvents": [
      {

      },
      {

      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I had performed a invoke to

> transfer 10 from a to b.

And i got this payload.

The payload is encrypted as the

> CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true and 
>   CORE_SECURITY_PRIVACY=true

I know we have to use the certificate to decrypt the payload and then might be use base64 decoding to get the exact payload back.

But my question is what are the exact function calls or exact steps involved in doing so ?